# Function name not defined error when i try to use recursion

Tags: python, pygame

I want to make a player that can shoot bullets. To do this i tried defining a `shoot` function that gets called when space bar is pressed. The function looks like this (p is the player object btw):

```
class bullet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.radius = 10
        self.shooting = False
        self.speed = 5

    def shoot(self):
        self.shooting = True
        if  self.shooting == True:
            self.x = (p.x + 60)
            self.y = (p.y + 25)
            self.x += self.speed
            self.y += self.speed
            pygame.draw.circle(d, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

        shoot()
```

I was hoping that the function would keep calling itself and the bullet would keep moving forward. However what actually happens is when i press space, it gives me an error

```
    shoot()
NameError: name 'shoot' is not defined
```

How i called the function:

```
while True:
    d.fill((98, 98, 98))
    p.draw()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pass

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            b.shoot()
```

Something i observed is that if i remove the recursion `shoot()` at the end of the `shoot()` function, it runs but the bullet stays in the same place as long as the space is being held down(as expected as recursion was removed). How can i fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: The others below have given answers as to why it's giving this error.  I just want to point out that the recursive design here is probably *not* what you want, and will eventually run out of stack-space, since it's an infinite recursive loop.  Have a look at pygame sprite objects, and the `update()` function.  https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html

Comment: Python isn’t <insert JVM language name here>, `this` isn’t the implicit scope for instance methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shoot` is *not* a function, strictly speaking.  It's an instance method, and must be invoked from a `bullet` object.  You need to use

```
self.shoot()
```

for recursion.

However, this is a poor way to keep the bullet moving.  This is a job for a loop.  Recursion is best used when you're calling the routine with a smaller version of the problem; this is just a continuance.

```
    while self.shooting == True:
        self.x = (p.x + 60)
        self.y = (p.y + 25)
        self.x += self.speed
        self.y += self.speed
        pygame.draw.circle(d, (0, 0, 0), (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
```

This raises the question of how you intend to quit moving the bullet.  You need something like

```
        self.shooting = (self.x <= x_limit) and \
                        (self.y <= y_limit)
```

Where x/y_limit are the upper bounds in that movement direction.

Comment: Just tried doing that but still got an error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: @hippozhipos that's a totally different error, unrelated to your first error.

Comment: @hippozhipos: that's because you have no exit from your recursion logic -- please see the second part of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must replace the recursive call `shoot()` with `self.shoot()` inside the `shoot` method. That ought to get rid of the problem and also give you the recursive function that you want.